# Unset a property in a ConstraintLayout xml

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a style with my default `ConstraintLayout` behavior. Now I want to reset `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` property in order to get correct constraints with `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`. How can I remove `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` from the view?

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="ConstraintDefault">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

**main_layout.xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDummy"
        style="@style/ConstraintDefault"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/Fab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**
`RecyclerView` overlaps `Toolbar` because of `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unset a Constraint Layout property one must shadow it with a negative number:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="-1"   // Upd: It's DEPRECATED! Use the method below
```

And it turns out that it's not a good idea to move *layout* properties to `style.xml`. It's much better to write *style* properties there (`background`, `textSize`, `font`, etc.)

### Update

With a newer Constraint Layout version this method doesn't work anymore and throws a compile time error. You should use a null reference as @jeff-padgett suggests:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@null"
```

Comment: This gives me an error when I use it, maybe it used to work, but doesn't seem to now.

Answer (score 1):

To `unset` a constraint set in a style, use:

`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@null"`

Answer (score 0):

For something like I think that a constraint layout is a overkill, you only have a recylcer view inside of it, I suggest that you use a coordinator layout instead. 
Something like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Your Context"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Agreed but I've provided only a part of the layout. And the question is about removing some properties recieved from `style`